# openxlsx - changing of header not wanted

Tags: r

I write a list of data.frames into an xlsx file with openxlsx. I do not like that the package changes the column names so that they contain the sheet name. Is there a way how to switch it off? I cannot find it.

```
library(openxlsx)

write.list <- function(data.list, filepath, digits=3, row.names=TRUE)
{
  wb = createWorkbook()

  for (i in 1:length(names(data.list))) {
    idx = names(data.list)[i]
    addWorksheet(wb, idx)
    rounded = data.frame(lapply(data.list[idx], function(x)
                                  {if(is.numeric(x)) round(x, digits) else x})) 
    writeData(wb, sheet=i, rounded, rowNames=row.names)
  }

  saveWorkbook(wb, filepath)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from where you are creating the `rounded` object. You need to use a `[[` instead of `[` to get the list current list element. Changing the the `rounded =` line to the following should correct this.

```
rounded = data.frame(lapply(data.list[[idx]], function(x)
```